# Using broadcast channel to communicate with firebase-sw and react component not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use broadcast channel inside firebase sw to post messages in the onBackgroundMessage, this is the code inside the service worker:

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
 console.log("Received background message ", payload);

 const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
 const notificationOptions = {
  body: payload.notification.body,
  icon: "/logo192.png",
 };
 //BROADCAST
 const broadcast = new BroadcastChannel("background-message");
 broadcast.postMessage("broadcast payload");

 return self.registration.showNotification(
 notificationTitle,
 notificationOptions
);
```

});

And in the app.js file I set up the listner to dispatch the payload of the notification using redux:

```
const broadcast = new BroadcastChannel("background-message");
  broadcast.onmessage = (event) => {
    console.log("broadcast message:", event.data);
    dispatch(getNotifications(event.data));
  };
```

I tried to push a test notification but its not working